# How to speed up the XP earning in Mechanic Simulator 2015?

Tags: car-mechanic-simulator-2015

I just started and repaired about 8 cars, but I not even reach 1000 XP, while I have already requests for works that need at least 3000 XP.

At a first impression it seems that XP is growing very slow. Is there a way to speed up the XP earning in Mechanic Simulator 2015?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but I remember that bigger jobs gave more exp since taking an item off and putting it back in gave 2 exp. So taking on big jobs where you had to disassemble the engine gave good exp.

I remember also that you could grind by say removing and putting back in the battery or the exhaust. But it's not worth it IMO.

Just keep doing jobs, smaller jobs go faster but I remember xp coming at a good pace and 8 jobs isn't much.